# Google Webmaster Tools reports fake 404 errors

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, 404, magento, web-crawlers

I have a website where Google Webmaster Tools reports 15,000 links as 404 errors. However, all links return a 200 when I visit them. The problem is, that eventhough I can visit these pages and return a 200, all those 15,000 pages won't index in Google. They aren't appearing in search results.

These are constant errors Google Webmaster Tools keeps reporting and I'm not sure what the problem is. We've thought of a DNS issue, but it shouldn't be a DNS issue, because if it were, no page would be indexed (I have 10,000 perfectly indexed).

Regarding URL parameters, my pages do not share a similarity in URL parameters that can make it obvious to me what could be causing the error.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: Its unlikely this will help but could we see a url of a page that is not indexed?

Comment: Hi @c-s-h any luck on your end? And sorry we cannot post URLs :( - and we're still having a rough time with this.

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Yes not much luck.

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Google reports are about 3-4 days old usually, look at the time at which the crawl happened. Also try to curl your urls to see if you see a 404 or 200.

Comment: Did you figure this out? We encounter the same issue although it's not on that many pages. Actually the Chrome add-on-tool "Check My links" shows that all links in my site is 404 but when I click them I see the page.

Comment: @user33932 404 allow content to be display in browser, to check either is 404 or 200 you can use header tool.

Answer (score 4):

Google offers a [fetch as Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587) option as part of [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

Use that tool to fetch your pages from Google's servers.   That will show you if it is a problem with connectivity from Google or with the Googlebot user agent as opposed to downtime of your website when nobody can reach it periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you temporary put noindex for those 404. It would very much harmful to your site where 2/3 is not indexed.

Then slowly identify what's the real problem. Since you can't disclose your link then no way we can tell what are the real problem.

But I sure you can find plenty of sources on "why google didn't indexed my pages".